# jquery, extract number value from name tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this being created by my perl script.

```
    print qq|
        \$('textarea[name=category$row[0]]').keydown(function(event)
         {
            \$("input[value=$row[0]]").attr('checked', true);
        });
    |;
```

Somewhere later, I have this, I want to reextract the $row[0] value but I am not sure how in jquery.

```
print qq|
<script>
    \$('#display_category').change(function() {
        var text = \$(this).val();

        \$('textarea[name^="category"]').each(function() {
            var foundvalue = \$(this).val();

            if (text == foundvalue)
            {
                alert("FOUND HERE " + foundvalue);

            }
        });
    });
</script>

|;
```

how do i reextract the \d+ from category and use it in my if condition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
alert("category1234".match(/\d+/g)[0]);
```

So something like:

```
var num = $(this).attr('name').match(/\d+/g)[0];
```

or (I prefer this one):

```
var num = $(this).attr('name').replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/8r8vs/3/

Comment: your example works but when i tried my code, my alert value is printing null

Comment: alert(\$(this).attr('name').match(/\d+/g));  i removed the match(\d+/g) and it reveals the category13 for example

Comment: Because you're extracting the value of the textarea, I think it's the name attribute you are after: `$(this).attr('name')`.

Comment: nevermind, forgot i was pasting my code into perl, had to backescape the "\"

Comment: @Gordon - also, `match` returns an array. Your code works because of implicit conversion, but I'll edit anyway.